# Isolation level and inconsistent state

Tags: java, sql, jpa, transactions

Suppose I have isolation level read committed

- My transaction reads A
- another transaction modifies A and B
- then I read B
- I do some businness logic that involves both A and B

So I will find myself working with a state that never existed.. ?
How do you cope with that ?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to lock a resource until it is freed:

Es:

- I read A
- another transaction (K) try to modifies A, but it is blocked, it can' t.
- I read B.
- I do some businness logic that involves both A and B
- K try to modifies A, it can do it beacause A is free in this moment and read B.

> Note: If K has to read A and B, but can' t read A it don' t block B uselessly.

Another solution is insert many controls:

Es:

- I read A.
- another transaction modifies A and B.
- I read B.
- I try to do some businness logic, but a control say me "Attention, the value of A is not updated!".
- I read the new value of A.
- I do some businness logic that involves both A and B.

Comment: you are right with repeteable read, what about read committed ?

Comment: I believe we can only warn the reader that the data after reading may change

Comment: I have found it: " 
READ COMMITTED
Specifies that statements can not read data modified by other transactions but which has not been committed. This will avoid dirty reads. Other transactions can modify the data in the interval between the individual statements of the current transaction, with consequences such as unique reading and the presence of ghost data. This is the default option in SQL Server."

On: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms173763.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more detailed information such as whether steps 1 and 3 are executed in same or different transactions. Also mention whether step 4,  i.e. "business logic" reads or updates A and/or B. Without more information it's not possible to accurately answer your question. At a high level -

1. Read committed: You see committed rows. In this case since A was read before another transaction modified it (assuming that your bullets depict the sequence of events I to IV), you may not have the latest value A after step II. If you read B in a separate transaction, you may see B up to date in step II.
2. Repeatable read: Consistently read same data in same transaction. If one transaction tries to modify A while another is reading it, depending on concurrency control mechanism, either repeat read or update will fail.

P.S. To execute atomic updates, you may consider using "select for update" queries.